# Display Flex not working with Divs created by Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, flexbox

I am making a 16 x 16 square grid in Javascript and have two for loops that are creating divs for the grid.  I'm assigning each row to be a flex-container and the cells inside to be flex boxes.  Instead of the divs showing up as a grid, they are showing up as a bunch of cells, one under the other.  Also, the borders are not showing properly too - so I tried adding a new class, called rows to get them to show, but that didn't work.  Does anyone have any suggestions on why this is not working?

```js
let board = document.getElementById("board");
let row;
let column;

for (let j = 0; j < 16; j++) {
  row = document.createElement("div");
  row.className = "flex-container";
  row.innerHTML = '';
  board.appendChild(row);

  for (let i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
    column = document.createElement("div");
    column.className = 'flexBoxes';
    column.classList.add = "rows";
    column.innerHTML = 'a';
    row.appendChild(column);

  }
}
```

```css
flex-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  width: 100%;
}

rows {
  background-color: pink;
  border-color: black;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 2px;
}

flexBoxes {
  flex: 1;
  border-color: black;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 2px;
  max-width: 20px;
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<div id="board"></div>
```

Comment: Voted to close since it's a small typo as others pointed out. You are missing the `.`.

Answer (score 2):

Your CSS classes are missing the `.` at the start:

```js
let board = document.getElementById("board");
let row;
let column;

for (let j = 0; j < 16; j++) {
  row = document.createElement("div");
  row.className = "flex-container";
  row.innerHTML = '';
  board.appendChild(row);

  for (let i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
    column = document.createElement("div");
    column.className = 'flexBoxes';
    column.classList.add = "rows";
    column.innerHTML = 'a';
    row.appendChild(column);

  }
}
```

```css
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  width: 100%;
}

.rows {
  background-color: pink;
  border-color: black;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 2px;
}

.flexBoxes {
  flex: 1;
  border-color: black;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 2px;
  max-width: 20px;
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<div id="board"></div>
```

[Class selectors - CSS: Cascading Style Sheets | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Class_selectors)